# What html does an asp:ImageButton render?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, imagebutton

If you have any links to a resource that shows a nice t-chart with asp controls on the left, and equivalent rendered html on the right, I would appreciate that.

Comment: So really what you want is a comparison between what code is entered into the templating engine and what comes out of it? Isn't that what reflector is for?

Comment: I'm thinking "handy cheat-sheet reference."

Comment: I'm thinking, too complex of a case to just list the simple versions.

Comment: So what you're saying is, asp controls can not be relied upon to emit consistent html? If you're not saying that, no need, I just said it. My MVC biases should be on plain display at this time.

Comment: I voted to close this because frankly I don't want to support webforms in any way. What a bad dream those things were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine renders like this: (image for a rule toggle that links back to the database)

```
<input type="image" style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Enable Rule Toggle" src="img/slider_on.png" title="Click to disable this rule" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderPage_name_ctrl0_EnabledToggle" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPage$name$ctrl0$EnabledToggle">
```

But notice that the code that demonstrates the actual "onClick" of the button is not shown. That's generated elsewhere in the page. Very important that a "button" class element actually has a click event.

Answer (score 1):

An asp:ImageButton tag renders an `<input>` tag of type "image". Or an imageinput, if you prefer.